# Is a query with intersect equivalent to those 'where a and b'?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a DB with postgresql and I wrote two simple queries

```
select page from title where word = 'france' and part = 'headline';
```

and

```
select page from title where word = 'france' 
intersect 
select page from title where part = 'headline';
```

I think they should return the same result but actually it's different. Any suggestions?

The table structure is simply id, word, page, part.

EDIT:

I tried also

> select distinct

but the query with intersect always returns some non relevant results.
This is a DB of a simple reverse table of some web news pages. So page, word and part are not unique. But no duplicated entries.

Comment: How is the result of one different from the other?

Comment: The first query returns the good result and the second has other non-relevant results.

Comment: non-relevant results? with word <> 'france' or part <> headline? can you rerun your test?

Comment: with the first query above, I got 12 pages which are all ok. But with the second, I got 71 different pages which are not all correct.

Comment: @darkjh - As described in my answer and then in Florin's answer, there is a condition where they can behave differently.  Can you give example source data?  I suspect that "page" isn't unique in your case and can be the cause of the difference in behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WHERE (a) AND (b)` is a boolean condition applied to Every record.  A record only gets included if it satisfies the *whole* condition.  In other words, only records where `word` is 'france' AND `part` is 'headline' *at the same time* will be included.

Is what you need more similar to using an `OR` in your condition?

```
select page from title where word = 'france' or part = 'headline';
```

Or are you having problems due to there being multiple records referencing the same page?

For example...

```
1 | 'france'  | 'aaa' | 'headline'
2 | 'france'  | 'bbb' | 'body'
3 | 'germany' | 'bbb' | 'headline'
```

`'aaa'` will be returned by both your queries.

`'bbb'` will be returned by only your second query.

Comment: Isn't this also true of an intersection?  Are you thinking of a union?

Comment: @Dems: `INTERSECT` means set intersection (rows present in *both* sets); you're thinking of `UNION`.

Comment: I'm aware of Set Theory, I'm pre-empting possible mis-understandings by the OP.  Which may be cheeky, but often happens ;)

Comment: ok I understand right now with your and Florin's explaination. But can I modify the intersect query so that it returns the right result?

Comment: @darkjh I added an update to respond to your question. You must add columns part and word in the select clause.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>The only technical difference I see is that intersect operation would generate unique `page`s. The first may generate duplicates.</strike>

**Update:**
They aren't the same.
the correct answer is what Dems already explained(I voted his answer):

```
page  word     part
1     france   headline
2     uk       headline
2     france   body
```

word = france AND part = headline `=>` page 1

word = france => page 1, 2 part = headline `=>` page 1, 2

intersection of previous two sets `=>` page 1, 2

**Update2:** Response to question: how to make intersect give the same result?
The intersect must be done over column in conditions, as here.

```
select page, word, part from title where word = 'france' 
intersect 
select page, word, part from title where part = 'headline'
```

Comment: And as a result, different behaviour if `page` is not unique in the source set.  (See example on my answer.)

Comment: To make intersect give the same result using the same structure, you can wrap it in a subselect: `select page from (select ... intersect select ...) as title`